# When posts by moderators are flagged, do they get any say on its status?

Tags: feature-request

Flagged posts go to the moderators for decisions, right?, They get to make the choice. let's suppose there's a user called User A, and User B, a moderator. When User A flags someone's post, User B and other moderators get to act on it. But if User A flags User B's post, does User B still get to make the decision? If they do, I think maybe this should be changed, as it would mean that the one moderator whose post it is could have a difficult time staying fair in their judgement of the post.

Comment: On a beta SE site that I am a moderator on, One of my posts was flagged once and it seemed that I still had the option to deal with/decline the flag. Of course I didn't - I left it to another moderator to deal with - but there didn't seem to be anything in the system preventing me from dealing with flags on my own posts. I wonder if it is different on graduated sites.

Comment: The flagged mod will still get to make a decision, but that's the reason why each site needs [more than 1 active mods](https://music.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) to avoid conflict of interest. On the other hand, normal users can't see which mod handles the flag though, so it's hard to argue if this happens or not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What we do is let one of the other mods handle it - it's easier and removes accusations of bias. The good thing is that there is visibility of these through the mods and the CMs, so the audit trail is there if needed.

I guess if the flag is stupid/pointless then we might deal with it ourselves, but generally it's just best to step away and let the next mod handle it.

Comment: Oh. I guess that makes a lot of sense. Thanks to all for your insights!